# Angular 7 - insert url on .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

**I have this code in my component.html file**

```
<button mat-flat-button class="mat-flat-button mat-accent ng-star-inserted" color="accent" (click)="playVideo(video)">
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="video.type === 'external' ? 'open-in-new' : 'play-arrow'"></mat-icon> 
<span class="alfadown">Open Video</span>
</button>
```

**And this code under component.ts file**

```
public playVideo(video: Video) {
    if (video.type === 'external') {
        window.open(video.url, '_blank');
    } else {
        this.store.dispatch(new PlayVideo(video, this.mediaItem));
    }
}
```

What I want is **to insert in the external link, this FIXED url on front of the (video.url)**
https://example.com/abc/123.php?

**Assuming** that the link generated by (video.url) is http://youtube.com/xyz **the full link should be**:

https://example.com/abc/123.php?http://youtube.com/xyz

How can I do this in angular 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a fixed string with no logic you can just concatenate the strings.

```
public playVideo(video: Video) {
    const prefix = "https://example.com/abc/123.php?";

    if (video.type === 'external') {
        window.open(prefix + video.url, '_blank');
    } else {
        this.store.dispatch(new PlayVideo(video, this.mediaItem));
    }
}
```